# how to insert data into db table with 3 distinct values but insert additional columns that are not distinct

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, composite-key

how to insert data into db table with 3 distinct values but also insert additional columns that are not distinct?
So I have table

```
data               user
__________________________________
user_id            user_id
train_code         train_code
version            version
score              score
                   first_name
                   last_name
                   nick_name
```

So my `data` composite key includes `(user_id, train_code, version)`

How do I insert data into `data` table from `user` table
where  (user_id, train_code, version) are distinct but also add score column?

Should I remove composite key constraint?

```
user_id |     train_code    | version
```

---

```
1004679 |     SGOP-0028     |   10    
1004679 |     SGOP-0028     |   11.1
```

Comment: Are there multiple values for 'score' for the same (user_id, train_code, version) in the user table?  If so, do you want to return all of them?

Comment: yes there are multiple values and I want to return any score from USER table. All I am concerned is if those first 3 are distinct.

Comment: if you will have multiple rows from User Table having same User_Id,Train_Code,Version then you need to remove composite constraint.

Comment: cause I know I can make them all distinct by placing distinct in front of the: DISTINCT user_id, TRAIN_CODE, VERSION, score;  Right?

Comment: same user with the same training code could have taken a different course version

Comment: Do you have any situation where table will contain rows where user_id,train_code,version will be same ?

Comment: Right, DISTINCT with those 4 fields will return the distinct combinations, but a unique key constraint won't allow for the multiple score values you need.

Comment: Do you have any situation where table will contain rows where user_id,train_code,version will be same ? NO I don't. @sumeetkumar I don't think so... :\

Comment: Then how do I add those values that do satisfy the condition, since it is throwing an error for those that do not @Goat_CO

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind **any** score when there are multiple scores for the same composite key, you could do something like this:

```
insert into data (user_id, train_code, version, score)
select user_id , train_code,version, max(score)
from user
group by user_id, train_code, version
```

Of course, my use of "**max**(...)" is arbitrary, and assumes that the particular score does not matter to you. i.e. you could use min(...) and it would be all the same to you.